# Function pointer definition inside a class template based on the template variable arguments

Tags: c++, templates

```
using FuncDef = void(int a, int b);

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class WrongFunction {
public:
    void F1(R(*Fn)(Args...)) {}//error: C2091 function returns function
};

template <typename T> class Function;
template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Function<R(Args...)> {
public:
    void F1(R(*Fn)(Args...)) {}
};

void test() {
    WrongFunction<FuncDef> errfunc;//trigger the above compilation error
    Function<FuncDef> func;//no problem     
}
```

(1) Why Function works but WrongFunction doesn't (check the compilation error in the comment)? What is the theory behind (e.g. something from cppreference which contains every details about C++)?

(2) (optional) Is there a way to make WrongFunction work but not in the form as Function?

Comment: Changing the declaration to `WrongFunction<void, int, int> errfunc;` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The follow class template:

> ```
> template <typename R, typename... Args>
> class WrongFunction {
> public:
>     void F1(R(*Fn)(Args...)) {}//error: C2091 function returns function
> };
> ```

defines a template parameter API which expects:

- a return type `R`, and
- a variadic number of arguments (of possible different types) `Args`.

Now, a template parameter pack may be empty, which hides your actual error here. In the instantiation of of the `WrongTemplate` class template:

> ```
> WrongFunction<FuncDef> errfunc;
> ```

you provide only a single template argument, which matches the first template parameter of the class template:

- `FuncDef` is used as argument for `R` in `WrongFunction`

whereas you are providing no argument for template parameter pack.

Thus, the compilers' error message is quite telling: you are instantiating the `WrongFunction` class template with a template argument provided for the template parameter `R`, which semantically signifies a *return type*, but with a *function type* argument. Meaning, in the associated specialization, `R` is a function type;

```
void F1(R(*Fn)(Args...)) {}

// resolves to, for WrongFunction<FuncDef> specialization
void F1( (void)(*)(int, int) (*Fn)() ) {}
      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- R
```

thus defining a function parameter that is declared to have the type "pointer to function (named `Fn`) with zero arguments that return a pointer to function with two arguments that return void". This is illegal, thus the compiler error.

---

In your other class template, you leverage specialization, constructing the primary class template API to have a single type template parameter, semantically intended to be provided arguments that are of type "pointer to function", as the the only partial specialization (as the primary template is not defined) is specifically partially specialized for this kind of argument.

---

> (2) (optional) Is there a way to make `WrongFunction` work but not in the form as Function?

The template parameter API of `WrongFunction` expects the client to explicitly provide the return type for the intended function pointer (of the member function) and the argument types by separate template arguments. It basically does not rely on deduction. Your second approach with specialization is the common one, and instead of fixing the likely ill-designed `WrongFunction`, I will note a similar but slightly different design of `Function`, which embeds a function pointer into its type instead. Thus could be useful if the member function of a given specialization should only use delegation to a specific function, rather than allowing dynamic dispatch delegation via function pointers of specific function pointer type (as function parameter to the member function).

```
#include <utility>

template <auto> class Function;
template <typename R, typename... Args, R (*Fn)(Args...)> 
class Function<Fn> {
  public:
    template <typename... FnArgs /* optionally SFINAE that FnArgs is Args */>
    void F1(FnArgs &&... args) {
        Fn(std::forward<FnArgs>(args)...);
    }
};

void f(int a, int b) {}

int main() {
    Function<f> func;
    func.F1(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: For the optional question: Make it `void WrongFunction::F1(R* Fn);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Any attmept to "fix" the `WrongFunction` (in a way that is not just making it `Function`) is likely to lead to confusion, as its template parameter API is miss-constructed to begin with, combined with the fact that (even if say `F1` were to be made a static member) the template parameters of a class templates are in a non-deduced context when used as function parameters in a member function of the class template (excluding some CTAD/ctor specifics). Specialization is a good approach here, but the type template parameter of `Function`:s primary template could likewise be made ...

Comment: ... into a non-type template parameter (set as `auto` in the primary template), as function pointers are valid arguments for non-type template parameters.

Comment: You're probably totally correct. I answered the optional question - but that fix is most likely  ill-adviced.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I expanded with something entirely different but nonetheless addressing the optional question.